# How to use map with search-box on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I want to create a google map in modal and it work, but after I tried to use
search-box on my map it error.

Here is my code:

```js
function initAutocomplete() {  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          placeMarker(event.latLng);
              });
}
function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker != null)
     marker.setMap(null);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
     });
    marker = marker;
         }
```

Here is my google map link.

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

Here is my function when calling my modal.

```js
$('body').delegate("#btnMap",'click',function(){     
     initAutocomplete();
     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });
     $('#ModalMap').modal('show');

    });
```